# Java can't connect to internet - java.net.ConnectException connection timed out

Tags: java, xml, maven, httpurlconnection, openjpa-maven-plugin

This is using OpenJPA 2.4.2 in my maven project to automate build-time enhancement of the JPA entities:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
    <artifactId>openjpa-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <includes>**/entity/*.class</includes>
        <addDefaultConstructor>true</addDefaultConstructor>
        <enforcePropertyRestrictions>true</enforcePropertyRestrictions>
        <persistenceXmlFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml</persistenceXmlFile>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>enhancer</id>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>enhance</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This is the exception:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1202)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:966)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1546)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:647)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:148)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(SchemaParsingConfig.java:582)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(SchemaParsingConfig.java:685)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaDOMParser.parse(SchemaDOMParser.java:530)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(XSDHandler.java:2179)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:576)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:613)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2446)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1767)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:740)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:374)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:613)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3132)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:852)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.meta.XMLMetaDataParser.parseNewResource(XMLMetaDataParser.java:423)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.meta.XMLMetaDataParser.parse(XMLMetaDataParser.java:346)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.meta.XMLMetaDataParser.parse(XMLMetaDataParser.java:323)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.meta.XMLMetaDataParser.parse(XMLMetaDataParser.java:304)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProductDerivation$ConfigurationParser.parse(PersistenceProductDerivation.java:833)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProductDerivation.load(PersistenceProductDerivation.java:375)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.ProductDerivations.load(ProductDerivations.java:310)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.ConfigurationImpl.setPropertiesFile(ConfigurationImpl.java:888)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.util.Options.invoke(Options.java:401)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.util.Options.setInto(Options.java:235)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.util.Options.setInto(Options.java:191)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.Configurations.populateConfiguration(Configurations.java:369)
at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PCEnhancer.run(PCEnhancer.java:4833)
at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PCEnhancer$1.run(PCEnhancer.java:4804)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.Configurations.launchRunnable(Configurations.java:764)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.Configurations.runAgainstAllAnchors(Configurations.java:749)
at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PCEnhancer.run(PCEnhancer.java:4799)
at org.apache.openjpa.tools.maven.AbstractOpenJpaEnhancerMojo.enhance(AbstractOpenJpaEnhancerMojo.java:131)
at org.apache.openjpa.tools.maven.AbstractOpenJpaEnhancerMojo.execute(AbstractOpenJpaEnhancerMojo.java:93)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
```

The exception above is swallowed by Java and it spits out this instead:

```
Cannot find the declaration of element 'persistence'
```

OpenJPA's enhancer is opening the `persistence.xml` and `Java 1.8`'s `Xerces` XML handling is trying to grab `http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd` off the net.

Took a bit of debugging to get to that find - grrrr.

I discovered the corporation's DNS where I work is crocked. I can get the XSD file in the browser - firefox or IE - but if I use `curl`, I see that it fails to connect and it's getting a bad IP.

How can I either:

(a) discover the IP address of the XSD file or
(b) instruct Java or Maven to get the XSD from a local file

Thanks

Comment: Although I resolved the issue one way by including the XSD file locally, I'd be interested to know how to discover the actual IP address of the XSD file at Oracle, given that my DNS server(s) is failing (apart from doing it from home later)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, specifying a local file in the schemaLocation was quite simple, but it was made more frustrating by IntelliJ which was not consistently copying the `persistence.xml` file across to the `target/classes/META_INF` build directory.

This is my localised `persistence.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence version="2.1"
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
            persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="default">
        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <class>com.xyz.entity.MyEntity</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```