# OPENJPA 2.4.3 apparently looking for persistence namespace on the internet

Tags: java, persistence, openjpa, persistence.xml

I'm using **OpenJPA 2.4.3** and I found a weird occurrence. When OpenJPA tries to access my **persistence.xml** when connected to the internet and DNS working it works smoothly.

However, when I'm not connected, it fails whenever it has to access my persistence file. It strongly seems to be trying to look for the namespace on the internet. I've run some network diagnosis and it's connecting to some hosts.

It's worth mentioning that hibernate does not have any problems running without internet access.

**Is there way to prevent/fix it???**

PS: **There's a similar question here:** [Java can't connect to internet - java.net.ConnectException connection timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44054265/java-cant-connect-to-internet-java-net-connectexception-connection-timed-out?newreg=fbf652ef2f2b469587059f91227604e8)

But his approach did not work for me without internet connection.

Also, I've tried different namespaces and versions but the result was always the same.

persistence.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.2"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
    <!-- Define persistence unit -->
    <persistence-unit name="jpa-mysql" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>

        <class>...</class>

        <properties>
            ...
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Error:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Explicit persistence provider error(s) occurred for "jpa-mysql" after trying the following discovered implementations: org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl from provider: org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl

    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createPersistenceException(Persistence.java:244)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:186)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:72)
    at au.com.marlo.connection.Connection.getEntityManagerFactory(Connection.java:13)
    at au.com.marlo.processors.SaveStoreProcessorTest.shouldProcess(SaveStoreProcessorTest.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: <openjpa-2.4.3-r422266:1833086 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.util.GeneralException: org.xml.sax.SAXException: file:/home/rafael/Documents/rskinner/Final%20Project/JBOSS%20FUSE/gbz-db-translator/target/test-classes/META-INF/persistence.xml [Location: Line: 4, C: 135]: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/home/rafael/Documents/rskinner/Final%20Project/JBOSS%20FUSE/gbz-db-translator/target/test-classes/META-INF/persistence.xml; lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 135; cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'persistence'.
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.meta.XMLMetaDataParser.parseNewResource(XMLMetaDataParser.java:426)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.meta.XMLMetaDataParser.parse(XMLMetaDataParser.java:346)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.meta.XMLMetaDataParser.parse(XMLMetaDataParser.java:323)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.meta.XMLMetaDataParser.parse(XMLMetaDataParser.java:296)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProductDerivation$ConfigurationParser.parse(PersistenceProductDerivation.java:811)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProductDerivation.parseResources(PersistenceProductDerivation.java:576)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProductDerivation.load(PersistenceProductDerivation.java:528)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProductDerivation.load(PersistenceProductDerivation.java:339)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProviderImpl.java:87)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProviderImpl.java:155)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProviderImpl.java:63)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:152)
    ... 31 more
```

**EDIT:** My friend opened a discussion on openjpa's jira and they fixed the problem on version 3.1.0. However, I think they only bundled the 2.1 version xsd, the 2.2 version may still not work.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-2781?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel